# SQL 2005 Express - New SP?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

When clicking New Stored Procedure I get a template with some lines of comments . Can this template be changed so that it does not give each time these comment line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't get rid of the comments. Comments are good. They are your friend.

That said, I don't have SQL Express 2005 here, but for SQL 2005 standard in the SSMS you can edit templates by going to View->Template Explorer. There is a template under "Stored Procedures" called "Create Stored Procedure (New Menu)" which is probably the one that you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Click "View"->"Template Explorer" (or alternatively Ctrl+Alt+T).

Scroll to "Stored Procedures" and Edit "Create Stored Procedure (New Menu)". and save